# nvidia-modeset error

Tags: nvidia, xorg

I enabled kernel mode setting with `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` and now getting this error frequently:

```
nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: Unable to read EDID for display device VGA-0
```

File reports that monitor is connected when it's not:

```
cat /sys/class/drm/card0-VGA-2/status 
connected
```

I tried to disable it with parameter in kernel `video=VGA-2:d` and after that`/sys/class/drm/card0-VGA-2/status` reported that it's  disconnected, but I still got errors in log. And the difference was that it didn't showed errors until I unlocked LUKS encrypted disk and OS loaded.

`xrandr -q` shows that `VGA-0` is connected, but I have only connected external monitor via `HDMI`.

How can I ignore/disable `VGA-0` or make that `nvidia-modeset` won't check this device?